# Xamarin.Android Secure Storage (Keystore)

Tags: android, xamarin, keystore, android-keystore

I want to store a some sensitive data (*Refresh token*) in the Android KeyStore.

I was going to use Xamarin Labs Sample ISecureStorage implementation

[KeyVaultStorage](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/e23832282b312cc6da6495da82f29081635fe1bb/source/Platform/XLabs.Platform.Droid/Services/KeyVaultStorage.cs)

But they use the Device ID as the password.... this can't be a secure way?!

And in their Xamarin.Auth Library, which leverages the Android KeyStore...they have the password hardcoded

[AndroidAccountStore](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/blob/master/src/Xamarin.Auth.Android/AndroidAccountStore.cs)

What's going on here?! Am I missing something?

On iOS its much simpler since the KeyChain relies on the PIN screen, which is enforced on iOS. What's the solution for Android? Don't say Shared Preferences. I need something more secure (KeyStore!!)

Answer (score 0):

The hardcoded value remained for backward compatibility, but API is added, so user can submit arbitrary password as a string. If password is not passed old hardcoded string will be used, which is security issue.

There are plans to add [Obsolete] Attribute to the insecure API.

It is up to user to decide how password will be generated/passed (UI or not so secure like in you mentioned DeviceID).

Regarding labs: are those Labs from Evolve16 preconference training?

If yes. The core of those labs is now integrated in the Xamarin.Auth, so the user can use SecureStorage and other utilities (CryptoUtilities) directly with Xamarin.Auth.

Comment: what's the recommendation on passing in a password here. It seems a lot of the examples were happy to just pass in the Device ID. Is there a reason behind this? i.e

Is the KeyStore only accessible by the application thread that created it? so even if you have the password, it doesn't matter? ....

Comment: key management is always the issue; if you pass in the device ID you are practically putting the key next to the locker so basically the only secure way is to use input from a user to unlock it

Comment: Thanks Roy! How does the native Android Keystore Provider overcome this limitation?